# GeoServer 2.7.1 fails to start after installing 11-Aug-2015 scripting extension

Tags: geoserver, extensions

This problem does not appear to be version specific for me. I have tried this several times with different versions and different system configurations. As the title states, when I add the script extension to GeoServer it stops working. Any suggestions? I am running this on Debian 8.

Here is an excerpt from data/logs/geoserver.log:

> 2015-08-12 11:52:31,066 WARN [support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'geoServerLoader': java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 2015-08-12 11:52:31,067 ERROR [context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wcsURLMapping' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver-test/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wcs-2.7.1.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'catalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localWorkspaceCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver-test/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.7.1.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'advertisedCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver-test/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.7.1.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver-test/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.7.1.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
>    ...

Comment: are you using tomcat 7.0.24? is so it is a known bug (https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7122) in Tomcat and fixed in newer releases.

Comment: If that isn't it, are you mixing release versions and nightly versions?

Comment: I am using Tomcat 8.0.14. I was mixing release and nightly versions, but I am still having the same problem after changing them both to the 11-Aug-2015 nightly. I am still getting the same warning message followed by a similar error, except this time the problem is in creating the "secureCatalog" bean defined in gs-main-2.7-SNAPSHOT.jar. When I copy over the script extension it replaces gt-process-feature-13-SNAPSHOT.jar, json-simple-1.1.jar, gt-geojson-13-SNAPSHOT.jar, and gt-process-raster-13-SNAPSHOT.jar, but accepting or rejecting the file replacement does not fix the problem.

Comment: Still having the same problem with the 15-Aug-2015 2.7.x build.

Comment: Still having the same problem with the 17-Aug-2015 2.7.x build.

Comment: Does it start with Jetty?

Comment: Same problem with Jetty.

Comment: On Geoserver 2.9.1 using Tomcat 8.0.23 I had the same issue and ended up just installing one of the old [2.4](http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.4.x/community-2014-08-20/geoserver-2.4-SNAPSHOT-python-plugin.zip)-builds of the plugin instead. In my case, errors similar to what you pasted extend as far back as 2.5, but not further. I'll report back if I find it's missing any functionality.

Comment: It works! Thank you for the recommendation of using a 2.4 build.

Answer (score 2):

The Python scripting extension works with version 2.4 from August 20, 2014, specifically this build of [GeoServer](http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.4.x/geoserver-2.4.x-2014-08-20-war.zip) with this build of the [Python plugin](http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.4.x/community-2014-08-20/geoserver-2.4-SNAPSHOT-python-plugin.zip).